# Need output in json format without single quotes. json.dumps vs json.loads

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, dictionary

Below is a simplified use case of what I'm trying to do. Any pointers or help is much appreciated.

```
>>> x
{'event': 'a'}
>>> type(x)
<class 'dict'>
>>> json.dumps(x)
'{"event": "a"}'
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>> json.loads(x)
{'event': 'a'}
```

Intended output is not a string but a JSON formatted output with double quotes as below
{"event": "a"}
The json.loads converts the string to a json format but the internal key and values are converted to strings which need to be enclosed in ""
The json.dumps converts the dictionary into the json format but outputs it as a string with single quotes.

The final intent of this is sending this to an endpoint that accepts only json format with double quotes "" and no single quotes

Comment: The code you have posted is impossible. The object referred to by `x` cannot change its type from dict to string.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you elaborate on this 'endpoint'?

Answer (score 0):

What you see after the `json.dumps(x)` is how python shows you the variable, it's the representation of it, but that doesn't mean it will send it with the single quotes.

The way you send the json depends on the library/module you are using to send the requests. But if you use the library `requests` you will be doing this:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> import json
>>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
>>> payload = {'some': 'data'}

>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

See the [requests docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/es/latest/user/quickstart.html#peticiones-post-mas-complicadas)